# Create optional numbers from 3 inserted positive digits

Tags: c#

I'm just struggled with question about that:
I need to write a  program that get 3 positive digits from the user and print all the 3 digits numbers that can be created from them. I'm not allowed to use recursion.. any ideas?

thanks

Comment: says you homework with repetition or without?

Comment: So which is it C or C#?

Answer (score 1):

Providing that `a`, `b`, `c` are given digits, e.g.

```
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
```

the implementation (**C#**) could be

```
  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    new HashSet<int>() {
      100 * a + 10 * b + c,
      100 * a + 10 * c + b,
      100 * b + 10 * a + c,
      100 * b + 10 * c + a,
      100 * c + 10 * a + b,
      100 * c + 10 * b + a,
  });

  Console.Write(report);
```

The output is

```
  123
  132
  213
  231
  312
  321
```

Note, that for (`a = 1`, `b = 2` and `c = 1`) you'll get only

```
  121
  112
  211
```

I doubt if this solution will be *accepted by your professor* (even if it doesn't have any recursion), but you can use it as a *test* when elaborating *your own routine*.